# How to work with 'generic xml root'

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-deserialization

Some (external) genius decided to provide us with XML:

```
<message_X>
    <header>
        <foo>Foo</foo>
        <bar>Bar</bar>
    </header>
    <body>
        <blah>
            <yadda1 />
            <yadda2 />
            <yadda3 />
            <contentX>
                <!-- message_X specific content -->
            </contentX>
        </blah>
    </body>
</message_X>
```

However, there are also other messages (say, `message_Y` and `message_Z`). These all have the exact same basic structure besides what is in the `content` node and, the reason for this question, the differing root-nodes:

```
<message_Y>
    <header>
        <foo>Foo</foo>
        <bar>Bar</bar>
    </header>
    <body>
        <blah>
            <yadda1 />
            <yadda2 />
            <yadda3 />
            <contentY>
                <!-- message_X specific content -->
            </contentY>
        </blah>
    </body>
</message_Y>
```

Why the root node isn't just named `<message>`, as I would've done it baffles me. Who comes up with this?

I have created an abstract class `Message` accordingly:

```
public abstract class Message {
    public Header Header { get; set; }
    public Body Body { get; set; }
}

public class Header {
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}

// Etc...
```

I was hoping I could then do this:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(XMessage))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(YMessage))]
public abstract class Message {
    // ...
}

[XmlRoot("message_X")]
public class XMessage : Message {
    // ...
}

[XmlRoot("message_Y")]
public class YMessage : Message {
    // ...
}
```

But that doesn't work: `InvalidOperationException: <message_X xmlns=''> was not expected.`. To deserialize I use:

```
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Message));
using (var sr = new StringReader(xmlString))
    return (Message)ser.Deserialize(sr);
```

I have no control over the XML and I'm not looking forward to implement this message again and again for each X, Y and Z.

I'll sort the `Content` part out by probably making `Message` into `Message<T>` and inheriting with specifying T etc. but that'll be of later concern.

I have also tried specifying `Message` as `Type` and `XMessage` and `YMessage` as `ExtraTypes` of the [XmlSerializer Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Xml_Serialization_XmlSerializer__ctor_System_Type_System_Type___) but that didn't help either. I have also tried to go the `DataContractSerializer` route with `DataContract`, `KnownType` etc. annotations but this didn't work either.

I would appreciate tips / pointers on how to solve this in a clean fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With @[steve16351](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3911233/steve16351)'s** ideas I wrote the following deserializer (I'm not interested in serializing, only deserializing):

```
public class XmlDeserializer<T>
     where T : class
{
    // "Globally" caches T => Dictionary<xmlelementnames, type>
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, IDictionary<string, Type>> _typecache = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, IDictionary<string, Type>>();
    // We store instances of serializers per type T in this pool so we need not create a new one each time
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, XmlSerializer> _serializers = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, XmlSerializer>();
    // And all serializers get the same instance of XmlReaderSettings which, again saves creating objects / garbage collecting.
    private static readonly XmlReaderSettings _readersettings = new XmlReaderSettings() { IgnoreWhitespace = true };

    // Lookup for current T, with this we keep a reference for the current T in the global cache so we need one less dictionary lookup
    private readonly IDictionary<string, Type> _thistypedict;

    public XmlDeserializer()
    {
        // Enumerate T's XmlInclude attributes
        var includes = ((IEnumerable<XmlIncludeAttribute>)typeof(T).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(XmlIncludeAttribute), true));
        // Get all the mappings
        var mappings = includes.Select(a => new
        {
            a.Type,
            ((XmlRootAttribute)a.Type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(XmlRootAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault())?.ElementName
        }).Where(m => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.ElementName));

        // Store all mappings in our current instance and at the same time store the mappings for T in our "global cache"
        _thistypedict = _typecache.GetOrAdd(typeof(T), mappings.ToDictionary(v => v.ElementName, v => v.Type));
    }

    public T Deserialize(string input)
    {
        // Read our input
        using (var stringReader = new StringReader(input))
        using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader, _readersettings))
        {
            xmlReader.MoveToContent();

            // Make sure we know how to deserialize this element
            if (!_thistypedict.TryGetValue(xmlReader.Name, out var type))
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Unable to deserialize type '{xmlReader.Name}'");

            // Grab serializer from pool or create one if required
            var serializer = _serializers.GetOrAdd(type, (t) => new XmlSerializer(t, new XmlRootAttribute(xmlReader.Name)));
            // Finally, now deserialize...
            return (T)serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
        }
    }
}
```

This deserializer uses the `XmlInclude` attributes to figure out which classes are to be mapped with what element-name using the `XmlRoot` attributes. Usage couldn't be simpler:

```
var ser = new XmlDeserializer<Message>();
ser.Deserialize("<message_X>...");
```

It does some internal 'caching' and 'pooling' of objects to keep it memory/GC-friendly and quite performant. So this solves my root-node-different-name-for-each-type problem. Now I need to figure out how I'm going to handle the different content-nodes...

<sub>** Who has since deleted his answer for some unknown reason...</sub>

---

The second part of the question, the 'generic content' was easily solved:

```
public class Blah {
    public Yadda1 Yadda1 { get; set; }
    public Yadda2 Yadda2 { get; set; }
    public Yadda3 Yadda3 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("contentX", typeof(ContentX))]
    [XmlElement("contentY", typeof(ContentY))]
    [XmlChoiceIdentifier(nameof(PayloadType))]
    public Payload Payload { get; set; }

    public PayloadType PayloadType { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Payload { ... }
public class ContentX : Payload { ... }
public class ContentY : Payload { ... }

[XmlType]
public enum PayloadType
{
    [XmlEnum("contentX")]
    ContentX,
    [XmlEnum("contentY")]
    ContentY,
}
```

This only leaves me wondering if I could apply the same idea on the root node...